# neoviz client visualisation for neo4j - protect passwords

Tags: security, graph, neo4j, graphviz

I'd like to use neoviz to visualise queries from neo4j, for public audience:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues/245

I looked at open issues concerning security of neoviz:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues/245

This is a beautiful post, but still a problem : cannot expose the credentials for accessing the db.

Here there is a comment to proxy the backend, but without an example:
https://community.neo4j.com/t/protecting-neo4j-password-when-using-neovis/548

And here an answer that the security issue of the password exposed, has not been addressed:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues/101

I am using a python backend (flask):
can you show how to implement any practice for using neoviz in a web app for public use, and protect the credentials ?

If not neoviz, any other library that could show the same results as neoviz without any data transformation other than simply sending the returned subgraph as a json ?